# Finding problem in adding 2 buttons for downloading the chart

Tags: html, json, graph, plotly, plotly.js

I've tried adding the buttons to download the graph that has been created in Plotly.js. But I've been able to download in only one format and I'm struggling to add another button for downloading in some other format.

Here is the code for downloading the chart:

```
var config = {
                      // ... other chart configuration options ...
                      // Add updatemenus for format selection
                      updatemenus: [{
                        buttons: [{
                          method: 'restyle',
                          args: ['visible', [true, false]], // Show SVG trace, hide PNG trace
                          label: 'SVG'
                        }, {
                          method: 'restyle',
                          args: ['visible', [false, true]], // Show PNG trace, hide SVG trace
                          label: 'PNG'
                        }],
                        showactive: false,
                        type: 'buttons',
                        direction: 'left',
                        pad: {'r': 10, 't': 10},
                        x: 0.1,
                        xanchor: 'left',
                        y: 1.1,
                        yanchor: 'top'
                      }]
                    };
                    
                    // Add event listener for download button
                    document.getElementById('download-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
                      // Get currently selected format (SVG or PNG)
                      var format = network.data[0].visible[0] ? 'svg' : 'png';
                    
                      // Convert the Plotly chart to the selected format
                      Plotly.downloadImage(network, {
                        format: format,
                        width: 1200,
                        height: 800,
                        filename: 'my_chart',
                        scale: 2
                      }).then(function(dataUrl) {
                        // Create a temporary link element to download the image
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = dataUrl;
                        link.download = 'my_chart.' + format; // Set filename with appropriate extension
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(link); // Remove the temporary link element after download
                      });
                    });
                    
                    // Update the chart with the configured options
                    Plotly.updateConfig(config);
```

As you can see that even after adding updatemenus I'm being unable to get 2 buttons in a dropdown menu format.

Here is the full code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            Visualization
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.58.5.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.5/dist/FileSaver.min.js"></script>-->
        <style>
            .graph-container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .main-panel {
                width: 100%;
                height: 800px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .side-panel {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -300px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            transition: right 0.5s;
            overflow-y: auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }

            .side-panel.open {
            right: 0;
            }

            .arrow {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: 20px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
            border-right: 20px solid #2196F3;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .arrow.open {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="graph-container">

            <div id="network" class="main-panel">
                <button id="download-btn">Download Chart</button>
            </div>
            <div id="graph" class="side-panel">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <!-- <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>   -->
          </div>

        <script>

            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("graph").style.width = "500px";
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "500px";
            }
            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("graph").style.width = "0";
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
            }

            const sidepanel = document.querySelector('.side-panel');
            const arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');

            arrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
            sidepanel.classList.toggle('open');
            arrow.classList.toggle('open');
        });

            //read the data from the json file
            fetch("data2.json")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then( data => {
                    //This part of the code is used to used initialize the variables which will be used to create a network graph

                    //Initializing array for storing the variables
                    var nnodes = data.nnodes;
                    var nedges = data.nedges;
                    var ncones = data.ncones;
                    var x = data.x;
                    var y = data.y;
                    var z = data.z;
                    var edge_x = data.edge_x;
                    var edge_y = data.edge_y;
                    var edge_z = data.edge_z;
                    var pressure_edge_gradient = data.pressure_gradient;

                    console.log(data)
                    // Velocity and the max and min values of the velocity
                    var velocity = data.velocity;
                    var max_velocity = data.max_velocity;
                    var min_velocity = data.min_velocity;

                    //This part of code is used to initialize the variables which will be used to create cones
                    var x_cone = data.x_cone;
                    var y_cone = data.y_cone;
                    var z_cone = data.z_cone;
                    var u_cone = data.u_cone;
                    var v_cone = data.v_cone;
                    var w_cone = data.w_cone;
                    console.log(x_cone[0])

                    //Keeping a list of true and false values for the concentration and the cones which are used while displaying through layout
                    var TrueList_cones = [];
                    var FalseList_cones = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < ncones; i++) {
                        TrueList_cones.push(true);
                        FalseList_cones.push(false);
                    };

                    //This part of the code is used to create a pressure graph
                    //Creating Edges for pressure graph
                    var pressure_trace_edges = {
                        x: edge_x,
                        y: edge_y,
                        z: edge_z,
                        mode: 'lines',
                        line: {
                            colorscale: "YlOrRd",
                            color: pressure_edge_gradient,
                            width: 5,
                            showscale: true,
                            //decrease the size of the colorbar
                            colorbar: {
                                thickness: 20,
                                len: 0.5,
                                x: 0.9,
                                y: 0.5,
                                title: {
                                    text: "Pressure",
                                    side: "right"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        type: 'scatter3d',
                        name: "Pressure Edges",
                        hoverinfo: 'none',
                        visible: true,
                        showlegend: true,

                        //set the position of the legend
                    };

                    //This part of the code is used to create a velocity graph
                    //Creating nodes for velocity graph

                    var velocity_trace_nodes = {
                        x: x,
                        y: y,
                        z: z,
                        mode: 'markers',
                        marker: {
                            size: Array(nnodes).fill(6),
                            sizeref: 0.5, 

                            color: "rgb(200,200,200))",
                            showscale: false,
                        },
                        type: 'scatter3d',
                        name: "Velocity Nodes",
                        hoverinfo: 'none',
                        visible: false,
                        showlegend: false,
                    };

                    //Creating edges for velocity graph
                    var velocity_trace_edges = {
                        x: edge_x,
                        y: edge_y,
                        z: edge_z,
                        mode: 'lines',
                        line: {
                            color: "rgb(200,200,200)",
                            width: 5,
                            showscale: true,
                        },
                        type: 'scatter3d',
                        name: "Velocity Edges",
                        hoverinfo: 'none',
                        showlegend: false,
                        visible: false,
                        showscale: false,

                    };

                    //Creating cones for velocity graph

                    var velocity_trace_cones =[];
                    //create the cones
                    for (var i = 0; i < ncones; i++) {
                        var coneColor = velocity[i];
                        var color = 'rgb(' + (coneColor - min_velocity) * 255 / (max_velocity - min_velocity) + ', 0, ' + (max_velocity - coneColor) * 255 / (max_velocity - min_velocity) + ')'; // create the color based on the velocity
                        var coneColorScale = [[0, color], [1, color]];

                        var single_cone = {
                            x: [x_cone[i]],
                            y: [y_cone[i]],
                            z: [z_cone[i]],
                            u: [u_cone[i]],
                            v: [v_cone[i]],
                            w: [w_cone[i]],
                            type: 'cone',
                            anchor: 'tail',
                            colorscale: coneColorScale,
                            showscale: false,
                            name: 'Velocity Cones',
                            hoverinfo: 'none',
                            visible: false,
                            sizeref: 0.5
                        };
                        velocity_trace_cones.push(single_cone);
                    }

                    var nscale = [0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
                    var steps = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < nscale.length; i++) {
                        var visible = Array(ncones).fill(true); // all cones
                        // visible[0] = true; // set the 0th cone to be visible
                        var step = { method: "update", args: [{visible: visible, sizeref: nscale[i]}], label: nscale[i]};
                        steps.push(step);
                    };

                    var sliders = {
                        x: 0.1,
                        y: 12.0,
                        len: 0.8,
                        pad: {t: 50},
                        steps: steps,
                    };


                    var data = [velocity_trace_nodes, velocity_trace_edges, ...velocity_trace_cones, pressure_trace_edges];

                    var layout = {
                      updatemenus: [
                        {
                          x: 1.5,
                          y: 15.5,
                          yanchor: "top",
                          xanchor: "left",
                          showactive: false,
                          direction: "Right",
                          height: 8000,
                          width: 8000,
                          buttons: [
                            {
                              method: "restyle",
                              args: ["visible", [true,true,...TrueList_cones, false]],
                              label: "Velocity"
                            },
                            {
                              method: "restyle",
                              args: ["visible", [false,false,...FalseList_cones, true]],
                              label: "Pressure"
                            },
                          ],
                        },

                      ],

                      xaxis: {
                      //visible: true,
                      //showgrid: true,
                      title:{
                        text: "Values",
                        font: {
                        size: 200 // Set the desired font size for x-axis title
                      }
                      },

                    },
                    yaxis: {
                      //visible: false,
                      //showgrid: false,
                      title: "Values_2",
                      font: {
                        size: 2 // Set the desired font size for y-axis title
                      }

                    },
                    zaxis: {
                      //visible: false,
                      //showgrid: false,
                      title:{
                        text:'Values',
                        font: {
                        size: 20 // Set the desired font size for z-axis title
                      }

                      },

                    },

                      sliders: [sliders], // add the slider to the layout
                    };

                    // Define Plotly chart configuration
                    var config = {
                      // ... other chart configuration options ...
                      // Add updatemenus for format selection
                      updatemenus: [{
                        buttons: [{
                          method: 'restyle',
                          args: ['visible', [true, false]], // Show SVG trace, hide PNG trace
                          label: 'SVG'
                        }, {
                          method: 'restyle',
                          args: ['visible', [false, true]], // Show PNG trace, hide SVG trace
                          label: 'PNG'
                        }],
                        showactive: false,
                        type: 'buttons',
                        direction: 'left',
                        pad: {'r': 10, 't': 10},
                        x: 0.1,
                        xanchor: 'left',
                        y: 1.1,
                        yanchor: 'top'
                      }]
                    };

                    // Add event listener for download button
                    document.getElementById('download-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
                      // Get currently selected format (SVG or PNG)
                      var format = network.data[0].visible[0] ? 'svg' : 'png';

                      // Convert the Plotly chart to the selected format
                      Plotly.downloadImage(network, {
                        format: format,
                        width: 1200,
                        height: 800,
                        filename: 'my_chart',
                        scale: 2
                      }).then(function(dataUrl) {
                        // Create a temporary link element to download the image
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = dataUrl;
                        link.download = 'my_chart.' + format; // Set filename with appropriate extension
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(link); // Remove the temporary link element after download
                      });
                    });

                    // Update the chart with the configured options
                    Plotly.updateConfig(config);


                        Plotly.newPlot('network', data, layout);
                    })
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSON file for the inputs:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "edges": [
        [
            1,
            2
        ],
        [
            2,
            3
        ],
        [
            3,
            1
        ]
        
    ],
    "nnodes": 39,
    "nedges": 52,
    "ncones": 52,
    "x": [
        121.028495788574,
        123.352821350098,
        140.785949707031
    ],
    "y": [
        116.316551208496,
        102.437530517578,
        107.810768127441
    ],
    "z": [
        59.3678894042969,
        85.5968399047852,
        94.6310577392578
    ],
    "edge_x": [
        121.028495788574,
        123.352821350098,
        null,
        123.352821350098,
        140.785949707031,
        null,
        140.785949707031,
        135.483871459961,
        null
    ],
    "edge_y": [
        116.316551208496,
        102.437530517578,
        null,
        102.437530517578,
        107.810768127441,
        null,
        107.810768127441,
        96.6482315063477,
        null
    ],
    "edge_z": [
        59.3678894042969,
        85.5968399047852,
        null,
        85.5968399047852,
        94.6310577392578,
        null,
        94.6310577392578,
        118.475326538086,
        null
    ],
    "pressure_gradient": [
        5319.79906208402,
        5319.22370839109,
        null,
        5319.22370839109,
        5317.72283129859,
        null,
        5317.72283129859,
        5316.47093892259,
        null
    ],
    "x_cone": [
        122.190658569336,
        132.069385528564,
        138.134910583496
    ],
    "y_cone": [
        109.377040863037,
        105.12414932251,
        102.229499816895
    ],
    "z_cone": [
        72.482364654541,
        90.1139488220215,
        106.553192138672
    ],
    "u_cone": [
        0.07808779308784423,
        0.856375076649549,
        -0.19742365213284796
    ],
    "v_cone": [
        -0.4662780954246829,
        0.26395186657205366,
        -0.4156386692370525
    ],
    "w_cone": [
        0.8811850170638401,
        0.44379177575368384,
        0.8878448052522355
    ],
    "velocity": [
        773.581933996682,
        3497.60743046076,
        2022.14115616565
    ],
    "max_velocity": 31155.0780437374,
    "min_velocity": 196.878430585795
    }
```

Please feel free to make the changes and let me know if there is anything wrong with placement of 'var layout' and 'var config' in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't work:

```
Plotly.updateConfig(config);
```

That function doesn't exist. Remove that line.

Because `Plotly.newPlot('network', data, layout);` is called after the previously mentioned it is not executed and no plot and no dropdown buttons show up.

You can actually just pass the config to `newPlot`:

```
Plotly.newPlot('network', data, layout, config);
```

https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlynewplot